# css: how to increase one character font-size without increasing whole text line-height?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a symbol from other `font-family` and need to adjust its size. Unfortunately `font-size:200%` increase line-height of whole line;

How to increase one character `font-size` without increasing `line-height`?

I know about "severing" the character with `position:absolute` but this also *shift* text horizontally. When what I want is something line `line-height: inherit` (which doesn't work).

```css
.increased {
  font-size:200%
}
```

```html
<p>normal</p>
<div style="background-color:yellow">.text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text  text text text text text  </div>
<p>increased (problematic)</p>
<div style="background-color:yellow"> <span class="increased">.</span>text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text  text text text text text  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're sure that it won't be the only character in that line, you can use `line-height: 0`. Otherwise you would have to manually adjust `line-height` value.

```css
.increased {
  font-size: 200%;
  line-height: 0
}
```

```html
<p>normal</p>
<div style="background-color:yellow">.text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text  text text text text text  </div>
<p>increased (problematic)</p>
<div style="background-color:yellow"> <span class="increased">.</span>text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text  text text text text text  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the element `inline-block` then you can adjust the `line-height` of only that character:

```css
.increased {
  font-size:200%;
  line-height:0.2;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>normal</p>
<div style="background-color:yellow">.text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text  text text text text text  </div>
<p>increased (problematic)</p>
<div style="background-color:yellow"> <span class="increased">.</span>text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text  text text text text text  </div>
```